# How to resolve "indicate anonymous lifetime <'_>" error?

Tags: rust, reference, lifetime, borrow-checker, borrowing

```
warning: hidden lifetime parameters in types are deprecated
  --> asd/src/app/qwe.rs:88:45
   |
88 |     fn add_meta_from_args(&mut self, args: &ArgMatches) -> AppRun {
   |                                             ^^^^^^^^^^- help: indicate the anonymous lifetime: `<'_>`
```

Where should I specify this anonymous lifetime? I don't really understand the need for it either. If the parameter is borrowed, why does it need a lifetime as well?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`ArgMatches<'a>`](https://docs.rs/clap/2.33.3/clap/struct.ArgMatches.html) struct within `clap` is generic over lifetimes. You haven't written out the full type of `args` in your function because you have omitted the lifetime parameter of the `ArgMatches` struct, which is why the compiler is complaining the type parameter is "hidden" and is suggesting you provide the full type for `args` by writing `ArgMatches<'_>` to make your code more explicit and clear.